# converting less mixins to scss

Tags: sass, less, less-mixins, scss-mixins

I was using the following LESS mixins to generate css for bidi usage.

```
.ltr(@ltrRules) {
  body[dir="ltr"] & ,
  body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"] & , 
  body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"]&    { @ltrRules(); }
}

.rtl (@rtlRules) {
  body[dir="rtl"] & , 
  body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"] & , 
  body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"]&    { @rtlRules(); }
}

.bidi(@ltrRules,@rtlRules) {
  .ltr(@ltrRules);
  .rtl(@rtlRules);
}
```

those would be later used like this:

```
// padding
// ------------------------------------------
.padding-start(@p) { 
  .bidi(
   { padding-left: @p } ,
   { padding-right: @p }
  )
}

.padding-end(@p) { 
  .bidi(
   { padding-right: @p } ,
   { padding-left: @p }
  )
}
```

this way when I eventually wrote:

```
div.myclass { 
   .padding-start(10px) 
}
```

I would get a set of rules that would style `div.myclass` with `padding-left:10px` if the div was in a left-to-right context or with with `padding-right:10px` if the div was in a right-to-left context.

I am now trying to convert this to SCSS and I have got to the following:

```
@mixin ltr {
  body[dir="ltr"] & ,
//body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"]&      
  body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"] & { @content }
}


@mixin rtl {
  body[dir="rtl"] & , 
//body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"]&    
  body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"] & { @content}
}


/*
@mixin bidi($ltrRules,$rtlRules) {
  @include ltr(@include ltrRules);
  @include rtl(@include rtlRules);
}
*/

@mixin bidi-padding-start($p) { 
   @include ltr { 
    padding-left: $p; 
   } 
   @include rtl { 
    padding-right: $p; 
   }
}
```

but I still have several issues:

1) If I uncomment the middle selectors in the rtl and ltr mixins I then get the following error: `Invalid CSS after "[dir="ltr"]": expected "{", was "&".  "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.`
I can live without this rule but I would prefer not to... I would expect it to compile

```
.myclass {
   @include padding-start(10px)
}
```

into:

```
body[dir="rtl"] .myclass , 
      body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"] .myclass , 
      body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"].myclass
```

2) I can't find a way to implement `@mixin bidi` because I cant find a way to pass along two content blocks to a mixin.

can someone help with this migration please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently SASS's functionality is limited to passing only a single `@content` block into a `@mixin`. There was a feature request discussion on a [github issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1943) but it was closed, and it looks like it never came to fruition.

In that discussion, someone [suggested a workaround](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1943#issuecomment-165882918) that effectively works with `@extend`. It works by using `%placeholders` to allow you to reference temporary rulesets. However, it seems a bit hacky and will need to be tested for more complicated rulesets with deeper nesting.

```
@mixin ltr {
  body[dir="ltr"] & ,
//body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"]&      
  body[dir="rtl"] *[dir="ltr"] & { @content }
}


@mixin rtl {
  body[dir="rtl"] & , 
//body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"]&    
  body[dir="ltr"] *[dir="rtl"] & { @content}
}

@mixin bidi {
  @content;
  @include ltr {
    @extend %ltr !optional;
  }

  @include rtl {
    @extend %rtl !optional;
  }
}

@mixin padding-end($p) {
  @include bidi {
    @at-root { 
      %ltr {
        padding-right: $p;
      }
      %rtl {
        padding-left: $p;
      }
    }
  }
}

.test {
  @include padding-end(5px);
}
```

Another option that may be more readable for future devs may simply be to explicitly call both mixins in place of `bidi`. It may be possible to write a script to make this migration.

```
@mixin padding-end($p) { 
    @include rtl {
        padding-left: $p;
    }

    @include ltr {
        padding-right: $p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stick to the two includes. :)
I think the LESS version was much nicer and easier to use.

Comment: Yeah! I like the original way you were doing it in LESS, it looks clean!